# how to chmod a dir from root's crontab

Tags: 18.04, bash, cron, chmod

Root's `crontab -e` has the lines

```
@reboot mkdir -p /tmp/vimbackups
@reboot chmod 777 /tmp/vimbackups
@reboot anotherCommand
```

After boot, the directory has been made, but it still has the default 755 permissions.  (The dir is for .vimrc's `set backupdir=/tmp/vimbackups`, if that matters.)

/var/log/syslog shows that all three commands were invoked:

```
CRON[937]: (root) CMD (mkdir -p /tmp/vimbackups)
CRON[940]: (root) CMD (chmod 777 /tmp/vimbackups)
CRON[938]: (root) CMD (anotherCommand)
```

This is so after every reboot.

If I chmod from a shell, or from `sh -c` or `bash -c`, then the chmod works.
Why doesn't it work from cron?
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Fascinating...no errors? There should be.

Comment: No errors in /var/log. Near that timestamp there's only a few files to examine.  Yeah, weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the both commands `mkdir` and `chown` are executed (almost) in the same time and something is getting wrong.

You could try to set an offset:

```bash
@reboot sleep 5  && mkdir -p /tmp/vimbackups
@reboot sleep 10 && chmod 777 /tmp/vimbackups
```

Or use the logical and operator `&&` to `chmod` after `mkdir` is successful:

```bash
@reboot mkdir -p /tmp/vimbackups && chmod 777 /tmp/vimbackups
```

But, probably, the best way is to use one command, not two:

```bash
@reboot mkdir -p -m 777 /tmp/vimbackups
```

- Note, this command will not touch the permissions of the tree (parent directories).